# jamroom: soundmanger 2, give media dir url?

Tags: web-applications

In Jamrrom, I applied a button player instead of a `jr_flash_player`, but I am facing a url problem when I give media dir. This is the url when that causes 505 errors.

```
$song_url = $JAMROOM_URL."/media/".$BAND_ID."/".$SONG_ID."_hifi.mp3";

a href="<?php echo $song_url; ?>" title="360 Demo:" class="exclude button-exclude inline-exclude"></a>

url = <?php echo $song_url; ?>
```

I use the sound manager2 360 button player, and I include soundmanager2.js and index-rollup.js. How can I pass media dir url in the anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

need some clarification, but can't use the comments for some reason.

Jamroom is smarty template based, your code above is PHP.  Where are you trying to use that code?

If you are in a template that has the song info, you can use {$SONG_LOFI_PLAY_URL} for the url of the lofi version or {$SONG_HIFI_PLAY_URL} for the hifi version.

If you want to create your own url you can format it like this:
/play.php?mode=song_hifi&band_id=99999&song_id=999999

take a look in the player_audio.tpl template in the Nova skin for a few more examples of different URLs